# Repository for funding opportunities

Tags: funding

I'm aware of many mailing-list and RSS feeds advertising about calls for papers/participation, available positions, events, etc, but I find it much harder to know about funding opportunities, such as calls for proposal, grant applications, etc. I'm based in the UK, and there are many funding agencies, including of course EPSRC and the EU, but also many smaller ones, and I'm pretty sure I'm missing interesting opportunities.

So my question: are there some website/systems where I can register my interest, and get to know about existing or soon to come opportunities?

In case it matters, I'm in Computer Science.

Comment: hi charles, did you find any useful resources? I would like to know, I am in the same situation. Thansk

Comment: Hi @flow: nope, sorry, I didn't find any useful resources, otherwise I would have put them here :)

Answer (score 2):

The biggest problem with such repositories is that someone has to maintain them. All the small funding agencies/foundations are usually obscure and will be hard to find on such a webpage.

Anyways, are you familiar with [Research Professional](http://www.researchprofessional.com/)? I use it from time to time, set up alerts for funding possibilities in my fields, so I get mails when someone new comes up. Might be worth a try...

Comment: hi posdef, did your institution pay for acccessing this resource?

Comment: @flow to be honest I am not sure, it could be the case.

Comment: @Opentheway Research Professional is superb! But it's a paid resource.

Answer (score 0):

These come from my [related question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/131538/is-there-a-free-database-of-grants-available-online) (which asks for **free repositories**, so not sure how much a duplicate it is, but I make the point in case someone wants to flag it as one):

- https://www.researchprofessional.com/
- https://www.grantforward.com/index
- https://www.grantselect.com/